# How to update the data of Button after some time in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am Creating **GUI** to show the ***Temperature and Humidity*** from the server using Tkinter. This GUI is developed to show temperature and humidity of multiple devices.

This is the button that I created to update the temperature humidity values,

```
self.add_button = tk.Button(self.window,
                       text="Add",
                       bg="DodgerBlue2",
                       fg="white",
                       font='Helvetica 12 bold',
                       command=lambda: 
             [self.add_command(), self.get_ip_data())
self.add_button.place(x=350, y=200)
```

My next step is whenever I add a new device then my main window shows separate buttons to show that, here is the code for that,

```
    def add_command(self):
        global button_counter
        global button_position

        if button_counter > len(button_position):
           return
        x, y = button_position[button_counter]
        self.result_button = tk.Button(self,
                                   text="",
                                   font="Times 15",
                                   bg="SkyBlue1",
                                   fg="black",
                                highlightthickness=2)
        self.result_button.place(x=x, y=y)
        button_counter += 1
```

This is the positions for the button to place on mainscreen,

```
button_position =[(100, 100), (300, 100), (500, 100)]
```

and finally this is the code to get temperature and humidity data from ip address and update into the buttons which I created,

```
    def get_ip_data(self):
        id = self.id_entry.get()
        ip = self.ip_entry.get()
        print(f"The id number is {id}")
        print(f"The ip address is {ip}")

        response = requests.get(f"http://{ip}/")
        data = response.json()
        print(data)

        temp = round(data['temperature'], 2)
        humi = round(data['humidity'], 2)
        print(f"temperature for id {id} is {temp}")
        print(f"humidity for id {id} is {humi}")

        self.result_button.config(text=f"Device 
                        {id}\nTemperature: {temp}°C\n
                        Humidity: {humi} %")
        self.after(2000, self.get_ip_data())
```

But the buttons I created doesn't update data from server. My GUI freezed. Can anyone suggest what is the mistake I made?

Comment: hint: `self.after(2000, self.get_ip_data())` immediatelly calls `self.get_ip_data()` and passes the result to `self.after`.

Comment: I can't understand @Bryan Oakley

Comment: What Bryan means is that the line is just like executing `result = self.get_ip_data()` and then `self.after(2000, result)`.